# Custom label for GitHub Action

Tags: github-actions, building-github-actions

Is it possible to set a custom build label/number/display name for a GitHub action?

With Azure DevOps Pipelines you can do this by echo'ing

```
##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$value
```

I'm looking for analogous functionality in GitHub Actions

Comment: I think its based on the name: entry in the main action file

Comment: yes but can I set it dynamically from inside the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

The name value is based on the file name and name: tag in the YML file under .github/workflows.

Comment: yes, but can I set the name to something dynamic from within the workflow?

Comment: The workflow name is static, but jobs and steps can be set dynamically using the matrix environment; see https://github.community/t/dynamic-job-names/139379/3

Comment: I'm looking for a way to take the version number which is generated via GitVersion and display it in the build label that is shown under the GH Actions tab...is there any way to do anything like that or to annotate the GH Action run in some way so that a build for a specific GitVersion number is findable?